# Run-time error '9' VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim FundN As Range
    Set FundN = ActiveCell

    'Add worksheet and name it using the value/text of the hyperlink cell on Sheet1
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = FundN.Value

    'Input data on created worksheet
    With Worksheets(FundN.Value)
        .Range("A5").Value = "Data"
    End With
    End Sub
```

The plan: Click hyperlink, which adds new sheet and names it using value of hyperlink cell. Then input data on newly created sheet.

The problem: Run-time error 9 on `With Worksheets(FundN.Value)` line. Confirmed that the new sheet is created and named properly before error.

The plea: Not understanding how it has no problem creating the sheet, but then has a problem finding the new sheet. Please help me get this error out of my life. Thank you!

Comment: If `FindN.Value` is numerical then this could indeed fail. If you do `With Worksheets(CStr(FundN.Value))`, does it help?

Comment: Indeed it does! It was numerical. Thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: You don't even need a variable for `FundN`. You can remove all references to it and replace `FundN.Value` with `Target.Value`

Comment: You could also useuse `With Worksheets.Add(..)` and have `.Name = FundN.Value` as the first line within the `With`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `FindN.Value` is numerical then indeed the reference could fail or even be to the wrong sheet. This is because `WorkSheets` behaves differently when you pass it a number or when you pass it a string. If a numerical value is passed, it is interpreted as an index, which can be out of range (Error 9).

As you intend to pass a name and not an index, make sure that you pass a string. This you can force with `CStr`:

```
With Worksheets(CStr(FundN.Value))
```